# Is there a double sided stack class in .net?

Tags: .net

I know about the System.Collections.Stack. I'm looking for a class that supports PushFront() & PushBack().

Comment: I'm sure if it existed you would find it in the collections namespace.

Comment: That which you call a *Stack* isn't one if it supports push back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just use/wrap `LinkedList<T>`? It has [`AddFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.addfirst) and [`AddLast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.addlast) methods. You can wrap it to hide the `AddBefore` etc. methods.

The common term for this is deque (it means double ended queue). If for some reason wrapping a  `LinkedList<T>` doesn't suffice (it should!), you could look at Eric Lippert's implementation of an [immutable deque](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue).

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you want something normally called a [*deque*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue). The closest I'm aware of in .NET is [`LinkedList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1). I don't believe there's one built from a circular buffer (expanding as required), which is the way you'd probably want to build it from scratch.

Of course, you could implement it yourself - but I'd probably use `LinkedList<T>` unless I had a really good reason not to. Eric Lippert also has [an immutable implementation you could look at](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/deque-cs) (see his [blog post covering it](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-10-a-double-ended-queue)), but obviously you'd want to write a bunch of tests etc... and you may not *want* an immutable one.

Comment: they should consider renaming this site to askjonskeet.com

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a deque. Here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/deque.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)? It allows addition to start, end and anywhere in between. If you do not want to expose some of the `LinkedList<T>` methods then you could always wrap it and only expose the methods that you want to expose.